# Number of ways to delete edges from an undirected tree such that each subtree has exactly 1 fruit

Tags: dynamic-programming

An undirected tree has $n$ nodes and some nodes contain a fruit. How many ways can we remove edges from the tree such that each sub-tree has exactly one node with fruit in it?

I found this question in an algorithm book without any hint.

**My approach :** Let $C[i]$ be the number of ways we can cut the edges if node $i$ was the root of that sub-tree. I am stuck here.

Comment: Hint: choose one fruit arbitrarily to be the root. How many other fruits are its immediate neighbours (ie. don't have to pass through another fruit to reach them)? How many places could you cut the chain of edges between the root fruit and each neighbour fruit to separate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root the tree at an arbitrary vertex. For each node $v$, we compute two quantities:

- $C_v$: the number of solutions for the subtree rooted at $v$, assuming that $v$ doesn't contain a fruit.
- $D_v$: the number of solutions for the subtree rooted at $v$, assuming that $v$ does contain a fruit.

(In fact, we do not need $C_v$ for nodes $v$ containing a fruit.)

Let's start by computing $D_v$. Let the children of $v$ containing a fruit be $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, and its nodes containing no fruit but whose subtree contains a fruit be $b_1,\ldots,b_m$; we don't care about the rest of the children, since any solution must not cut any edge involved in them. (A child $w$ is of the third type if $C_w = 0$.) Any solution must cut each $(v,a_i)$ edge. For each $(v,b_j)$ edge which is not cut, we need a solution in the subtree rooted at $b_j$ which behaves as if $b_j$ contained a fruit. Hence
$$
 D_v = \prod_{i=1}^n D_{a_i} \prod_{j=1}^m (C_{b_j} + D_{b_j}).
$$

Computing $C_v$ is similar. Define $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m$ as before; once again, we don't care about the rest of the children. This time one of the edges from $v$ to one of its children must connect it to a fruit-bearing vertex. This can be either $(v,a_i)$ or $(v,b_j)$, and in the latter we do not artificially add a fruit to $b_j$. Therefore
$$
 C_v = \prod_{i=1}^n D_{a_i} \prod_{j=1}^m (C_{b_j} + D_{b_j}) \left(n + \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{C_{b_j}}{C_{b_j} + D_{b_j}} \right).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the base cases of Cv and Dv?

Comment: You don’t need a special base case. A leaf is a node without any children.

Comment: D[leaf] = 1 and C[leaf] = 1? Can I ask why did you do +∑Cbj/(Cbj+Dbj)?

Comment: I get C[leaf]=0.